# Result of TypeScript class factory mixin "is not a constructor function"

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use mixin classes in TypeScript. But the return value of the mixin application (Sizeable.mixin()) in the below code) is "not a constructor function" although, as you clearly see in the error output, the first part of its type is `new (...args: any[]):`, so one would think it is a constructor function:

[image]

Any idea why the `Parent`, which is clearly a constructor because it has the `{ new (...args: any[]):` part in its type, may not be allowed to be extended by a class?

Comment: Can you try moving the code out of a screenshot and in the question and going through  more thorough explanation of what the code does and what the problem is? From first glance while I don't completely understand it fully I can see that `Parent` is not actually a constructor it only contains a constructor.

Comment: @apokryfos How does it contain a constructor?Isn't that syntax the constructible interface syntax, meaning the interface type is a constructor. For example: `interface Ctor { new(arg: string): Ctor }`. Isn't this a type representing a constructible?

Comment: A constructible yes. But constructible contains a constructor. The constructor itself is something like `type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;`

Comment: We need the code of `Sizeable.mixin`, or at least the declaration with typings.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a mixin will return an intersection between what is added by the mixin and the type of the original constructor `T`. This works out well in a non-generic context and the resulting merged class will work. The problem is that while in another mixin, `T` is not yet known, so the intersection `mxinStuff & T` will not be resolvable to a constructor:

```
function mixin1<T extends new (... a: any[]) => any> (ctor: T) {
    return class WithMixin1 extends ctor {
        mixin1() {}
    }
}

function mixinMixed<T extends new (... a: any[]) => any> (ctor: T) {
    return class WithMixin2 extends mixin1(ctor) { // Type '{ new (...a: any[]): mixin1<T>.WithMixin1; prototype: mixin1<any>.WithMixin1; } & T' is not a constructor function type.
        mixin2() {}
    }
}
```

We can do some type surgery on the result of `mixin1` to get is to work as a base type for a new class and then assert that the new class is what would be produced as if we extended  the way we originally wanted to do the extension:

```
function mixin1<T extends new (... a: any[]) => any> (ctor: T) {
    return class WithMixin1 extends ctor {
        mixin1() {}
        static staticMixin1() {}
    }
}
const mixin1BaseType = () => mixin1(class{});    
type Mixin1Type = ReturnType<typeof mixin1BaseType>

function mixinMixed<T extends new (... a: any[]) => {a : string }> (ctor: T) {
    class WithMixin2 extends (mixin1(ctor) as unknown as {
        new (... a: any[]): {a : string } // we pretend this returns the constraint of T
    } & Mixin1Type /* add mixin back in but as instantiated for an empty class*/ ) {
        mixin2() {
            this.a
            this.mixin1()
            WithMixin2.staticMixin1();
        }
        static staticMixin2() {}
    }

    return WithMixin2 as unknown as {
        new (...a: ConstructorParameters<T>): WithMixin2 & InstanceType<T>
    } & T & Mixin1Type & typeof WithMixin2
}

type AnyContructor = new (... a: any[]) => any

let m = mixinMixed(class {
    a: string = "a";
    b: string = "b";
    m() {}
    static staticM() {}
})

let s  = new m();
// instance members are accessible
s.a
s.b
s.m();
s.mixin1();
s.mixin2();

// Staic methods are accessible
m.staticMixin1()
m.staticMixin2()
m.staticM();
console.log(s)
```

Comment: That is indeed horrendous. It won't be friendly to write and compose mixins that way. For example, what about a mixin that uses a mixin that uses a mixin that uses a mixin, and some of those mixins use multiple mixins? That's what I have in practice (trying to convert from JS to TS).

Comment: @trusktr Yeah that is ugly, I can try to put it in a utility function to hide some of it. It will not get worse if you have more inherited mixins as the type of the previous mixin in the chain will already contain whatever mixins it used.

Comment: I suppose the utility function would have a required generic arg. That would be cleaner, but would it be type safe?

Comment: @trusktr I won't know until I try to write it .. I'll do some experimenting tomorrow and post the results .. we'll see

Answer (score 1):

idk why the above answer is so complicated. You can just do `InstanceType<typeof YourMixedType>`.

Example based on the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)

```
class Sprite {
  name = "";
  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};

// This mixin adds a scale property, with getters and setters
// for changing it with an encapsulated private property:

function Scale<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Scaling extends Base {
    // Mixins may not declare private/protected properties
    // however, you can use ES2020 private fields
    _scale = 1;

    setScale(scale: number) {
      this._scale = scale;
    }

    get scale(): number {
      return this._scale;
    }
  };
}

type Scalable = InstanceType<ReturnType<typeof Scale>>;

const EightBitSprite = Scale(Sprite);
type EightBitSpriteType = InstanceType<typeof EightBitSprite>;

const flappySprite = new EightBitSprite("Bird");

// Now lets use the types!
foo(flappySprite);
bar(flappySprite);
baz(flappySprite);

function foo(sprite: EightBitSpriteType) {
}
function bar(sprite: Scalable) {
}
function baz(sprite: Sprite) {
}
```

See it in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAOAnAlgFwKbQN4ChrQDswBbTAXmgCJKBuPaAD2goAY78BPZ6Nne4APYEIqRAFdgqAYgAURUgC5oIlAQDmASmz18qABbIIAOnnlCJdO2gBfHLZyoO8TAGEhKiVMTcC6AO7QMkbBYIhqEEpgBBwA2gC6WmQAfNjWdDgA9BnQACoGMMTIDMgE0GAAJuUwYMrAYCCYSALOiI4ANNB+aHrQauioGIjVBOXK-YMQmdkAZtLQwHpRaiVq0Gid3WWl6AR18BBi4BijSMgAbmAY0E0tjgp802K7qMhCcHUNADw5AEKQmOgGBgRjA3MJRJ5pEkZH8IOglL9-lpcPhEP0xIhSqBIDBYB8VtBAcCqtBYZgUfhoFloABZIolApgLgEASoaDldDYtHXFAXDAZJoYSToE6IZroVrIdCTSlU7J6AR+dBnCUdDgCMTzKLQMRw6AAUVgACYWCaeedLphplKQFUdNAAPoQD5mACM6VlcNQePq6Bkzt9SgIYmIACMJcj7bp8kYnS7uAGGlZ8PZZX02Ym-RogyHw94KbK0agMaV9IZY5nkzZ6Gk7HxHM53vUwKGGtwAJLgqLAdA5JzoT4AJXRmL7zk+DfQAmmTYaSSS6UE4INyDUelQPzQCBQVwoPoaMm3aHQGjok5Xa43W9OGDHZk7Im7vf7E-704v6833pv6AXfCXIjQNM4DwPAHBHruhD+B+V7fjufqUJuiDlJQp4PAIAgyMBYCgeBP5oaGoRYSBYEQSedCEQAXsROGkfh6SPM8rylLMmEQD+Sj6qun7XvBd6RrYjGSMx0CEbI7HwUo+4tg0Ak4EJLxvFR-ocXA+HaNYQA).